# How should I return different types in a method based on the value of a string in Java?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I have come to having the following problem:

I have created several classes which all implement the interface "Parser".  I have a JavaParser, PythonParser, CParser and finally a TextParser.

I'm trying to write a method so it will take either a File or a String (representing a filename) and return the appropriate parser given the extension of the file.

Here is some psuedo-code of what I'm basically attempting to do:

```
public Parser getParser(String filename)  
{
    String extension = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf("."));

    switch(extension)
    {
        case "py": return new PythonParser();
        case "java": return new JavaParser();
        case "c": return new CParser();
        default: return new TextParser();
    }
}
```

In general, is this the right way to handle this situation?  Also, how should I handle the fact that Java doesn't allow switching on strings?  Should I use the .hashcode() value of the strings?

I feel like there is some design pattern or something for handling this but it eludes me.  Is this how you would do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called the [Factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and it seems like a pretty good way to handle your problem.  One way you can get around the "Java doesn't allow switching on strings" problem is by using an `if`...`else` statement.

```
if (extension.equals("py")) {
    return new PythonParser();
}
else if(extension.equals("java")) {
    return new JavaParser();
}
else ...
```

Comment: To the OP: note the use of `.equals()` as opposed to `==`. That's important! Google "java string equals" or something to see why.

Answer (score 11):

1. You can simply use several `if` statements one after another.
2. You can create special `enum` for your languages and use it in your switch statement.
3. You can use `Map` where languages are keys and parser's prototypes are values.

3rd option looks interesting as for me. The code will look like:

```
return parsers.get(extention).newInstance();
```

---

And here is a little tricky implementation of the 2nd option with enum:

```
enum Language {

    JAVA {
        public Parser getParser () {
            return new JavaParser ();
        }}, 
    PYTHON {
        public Parser getParser () {
            return new PythonParser ();
        }}, 
    TEXT {
        public Parser getParser () {
            return new TextParser ();
        }};

    public Parser getParser () {
        return null;
    }

    public static Language getLanguage (String extention) {
        try {
            return valueOf (extention);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return TEXT;
        }
    }
}

...

public Parser getParser(String filename) {
    String extension = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf("."));    
    return Language.getLanguage (extension).getParser ();
}
```

Comment: Personally, I'd prefer the enum implementation, since it allows proper switching and needn't assume a no-args constructor. Code needn't be much longer: Parsers.valueOf(extension).getParser();

Answer (score 1):

you can use an `enum` to decide once which language are you dealing with and then use it around (also in switch statements):

```
enum Type { JAVA, PYTHON, CPP, C, PERL };

Type getType(String filename)
{
  // do your if chain here
  return JAVA;
}

public Parser getParser(String filename)  
{
    switch(getType(filename))
    {
        case PYTHON: return new PythonParser();
        case JAVA: return new JavaParser();
        case C: return new CParser();
        default: return new TextParser();
    }
}
```

Relating to your first question: your approach is OK, it is called **factory pattern** when you have something that builds many kinds of concrete implementations of an interface (in your case `Parser`) choosing which one at run-time

Comment: You could even hide the getType method inside the enum (and make the enum top-level) for a stronger separation of concerns

Answer (score 1):

> In general, is this the right way to
>   handle this situation?

This seems to be the right way, given that `PythonParser`, `JavaParser` etc implements or are subclasses of `Parser`

> Also, how should I handle the fact
>   that Java doesn't allow switching on
>   strings?

Use if..else if; You don't have to use hashcodes or anything. Check out `equals()` method on strings.

> I feel like there is some design
>   pattern or something

[yes](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html)

Answer (score 1):

PythonParser, JavaParser, and CParser should all be subclasses of Parser, or Parser could be an Interface that they all implement.

You can easily get around the limitation of case statements by using if/else if.

DO NOT use the hash code of the string. Many many strings map to the same hash code, so just because extension.hashCode()=="java".hashCode() does not necessarily mean that extension.equals("java"). With just 3 strings here the probability of an accidental collision is small, but programs that "ought to work most of the time as long as we're lucky" are bad news. In this case, the program could work perfectly correctly with this particular collection of strings, and then some time later you add CobolParser and suddenly it quits working.

Someone mentioned using enums. In general it is much better to use enums to identify "types" of things than to use strings. But in this case you're extracting the string from a file name, so you'd have to run it through an if/else if block to convert it to the enum, and then test the enum. As you promptly create a type-specific parser, it's unlikely you'd save the enum or ever look at it again, so I don't think you'd gain anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use of interface is correct in this situation. Your interface should expose the methods so that the calling classes do not need to cast themselves into specific parser implementation.

Regarding the switch case, if you are using jdk1.5 or higher, you should define enum for these strings and you can use swicth case easily.

Answer (score 0):

I would:

```
public Parser getParser(String filename)  {
    String extension = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf("."));

    if( "py".equals(extension)  ) { return new PythonParser() }
    if( "java".equals(extension)) { return new JavaParser();  }
    if( "c".equals(extension)   ) { return new CParser();     }

    return new TextParser();
}
```

About the question in your title

> *How should I return different types in a method based on the value of a string in Java?*

You can't you have to return only a single type. What you can do is to return subtypes of that type, so if your parsers are subclasses or implement the `Parser` class/interface the code above will work perfectly.

ie.

```
public interface Parser {
    //parser methods  
    ...
}
class PythonParser implements Parser {
     // parser implementation
     ...
}
class JavaParser implements Parser {
     // parser implementation
     ...
}
class CParser implements Parser {
     // parser implementation
     ...
}
```